# How to prevent UIWebViewBounce, "rubber banding"

Tags: cordova, ios7, uiwebview, ionic-framework

Using ionicframework with Cordova CLI v3.4

I'm using the following preferences in my config.xml file(s).

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Compiling through the CLI and XCode doesn't seem to fix anything.

I then did a search for `DisallowOverscroll` project wide and made sure all values were set to `true`

I'm still getting rubberbanding though on my view. Anyone have an idea what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to this post on ionics forums](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/disable-content-bouncing/2371):

"It's an ionic thing, not a cordova issue.

```
 <ion-content
         has-bouncing="false"
         start-y="55"
         padding="true"
         has-tabs="true"
         has-header="true"
         >
```

Use the `has-bouncing` attribute to disable the bounce effect on the `ion-content` directive"

Just had to set the attr `has-bouncing="false"`, I don't know why that could override the Cordova config settings though.

Comment: That does not override Cordova's settings: by default with Cordova you have that bounce effect on the entire app itself, meaning that instead your scrollable content to bounce, it's your entire app that bounces, which is not really nice. With Ionic the bounce is only within your ion-content, which is usually fine to have by default.

Comment: How to do it in ionic 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this on the HTML+JS side, provided that the HTML document is *not* taller than the WebView viewport (aka window.height in JS). You do this by calling preventDefault on the 'touchmove' event at the appropriate time (namely when the element and all its parents have nothing to scroll in the direction the user began moving their finger).

I will show you actual code to do it, without using jQuery ... but you'll have to implement Q.addEventListener and Q.removeEventListener yourself (or use jQuery).

```
function _touchScrollingHandler(event) {
    var p = event.target;
    var pos;
    var scrollable = null;
    do {
        if (!p.computedStyle) {
            continue;
        }
        var overflow = p.computedStyle().overflow;
        var hiddenHeight = p.scrollHeight - p.offsetHeight;
        var s = (['hidden', 'visible'].indexOf(overflow) < 0);
        if ((s || p.tagName === 'HTML') && hiddenHeight > 0) {
            if ((Q.Pointer.movement.positions.length == 1)
            && (pos = Q.Pointer.movement.positions[0])) {
                var sy = Q.Pointer.getY(event)
                    + Q.Pointer.scrollTop();
                if ((sy > pos.y && p.scrollTop == 0)
                || (sy < pos.y && p.scrollTop >= hiddenHeight)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            scrollable = p;
            break;
        }
    } while (p = p.parentNode);
    if (!scrollable) {
        Q.Pointer.preventDefault(event);
    }
}

var Q = {
    preventTouchScrolling: function () {
        Q.addEventListener(window, 'touchmove', _touchScrollingHandler);
    },
    restoreTouchScrolling: function () {
        Q.removeEventListener(window, 'touchmove', _touchScrollingHandler);
    }
};
```